# How to update changes to the worldserver config file

Tags: docker, azerothcore

I'm extremely new to this. I've managed to get a server up and running, but i'm struggling on understanding how to apply changes to the worldserver.conf.

I've made the changes i'd like already, but cannot figure out how to apply this to the server.

Any help would be appreciated, please :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is `worldserver.conf`? How do you run and create the container? Do you use `Dockerfile`? Do you use `docker-compose.yml` file? Do you use none of them?

Answer (score 0):

For many settings, you can just edit the `worldserver.conf` file and then run a `.reload conf` command (in-game, or in console without the dot).

Some settings require a whole server restart though, so sometimes you need to restart the `worldserver` process to see the changes.